# Clear state on handleChange function

Tags: reactjs

I have a function on my App component to handle the parent's state changes on children components, I call the function to update each page's change.

The `makeHandleChange` function on App component:

```
  makeHandleChange = (pageName, change) => {
    this.setState({
      ticket: { ...this.state.ticket, [pageName]: change },
    });
  };
```

Ticket state:

```
  state = {
    ticket: {
      departments: {},
      categories: {},
      subCategories: {},
    },
  };
```

On each page I call the `makeHandleChange` function to set the pages' changes, for example:

```
makeHandleChange('categories', pageChanges)
```

On the last page of my app I would like to clear the entire `ticket` state, can I do that by calling the `makeHandleChange` function?

Comment: better to add a new method: `clearTicket() { this.setState({ ticket: {} }) }` and use that to clear the ticket value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Yes, you can.`

The solution includes calling the function `makeHandleChange()` multiple times - and since `setState()` function is `async`, it is preferred to use the optional function parameter instead to prevent side effects:

```
makeHandleChange = (pageName, change) => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    ticket: { ...state.ticket, [pageName]: change },
  }));
};
```

This way you will update the state based on the current state.

## Direct answer to your question:

### Option #1

Call the function 3 times.

```
makeHandleChange('departments', {});
makeHandleChange('categories', {});
makeHandleChange('subCategories', {});
```

### Option #2 (For a larger size of pages)

```
const pagesList = [
  'departments',
  'categories',
  'subCategories',
  // etc..
];
for (let i = 0; i < pagesList.length; i++)
  makeHandleChange(pagesList[i], {});
```

## Alternative solution

As suggested by `Mayank Shukla`, create an additional function to handle this special case - and prevent unwanted behaviour:

```
function clearTicket() {
 this.setState({ ticket: {} }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a few other pages so will have to call it about 6 times, I'm looking for a more elegant solution...:)

Comment: To my eyes its elegant as it gets. As Mayank said you can make a new clearTicket() function that might be a little more elegant, But its a good solution if it works

Comment: You can't do that with the current function. you should add a new function like Mayank Shukla suggested, or make for loop over the function with the an array of page names.

Comment: @Haim763 I ended up doing it with an array (#2) but for some reaso only the last item of the array is getting cleared, I `console.log` and it actually reaches the `makeHandleChange` function acording to the items on the `pagesList` array, not sure why not all stats are being cleared.

Comment: You should change your makeHandleChange function to use setState with the optional function parameter. I updated the answer with details.